# What surgery characteristics make fentanyl a suitable painkiller for certain surgeries?

Tags: surgery, analgesics, pain-management

I read on https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/dea-fentanyl-opioid-crisis-suicide-b2236501.html (emphasis is mine):

> [Fentanyl] is better known for its potent illegal street form, which sometimes causes shock overdoses, though it retains legitimate use as a painkiller and medicine for **certain** surgeries.

I'd like to understand why fentanyl is suitable only for certain surgeries and not all. What surgery characteristics make fentanyl a suitable analgesic for certain surgeries?

Comment: I'm not an anesthesiologist, but you might find this review interesting: [A Review of the Use of Fentanyl Analgesia in the Management of Acute Pain in Adults](https://pubs.asahq.org/anesthesiology/article/90/2/576/37742/A-Review-of-the-Use-of-Fentanyl-Analgesia-in-the). "Fentanyl's popularity as an intraoperative agent relates directly to the cardiovascular stability it provides, even in critically ill patients."

Answer (score -2):

Reddit surgeon [insomnia_owl1234](https://www.reddit.com/user/insomnia_owl1234) [shared](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskDocs/comments/z6tmro/weekly_discussiongeneral_questions_thread/iyoz2i4/?%2524deep_link=true&correlation_id=7f9500d7-bce6-434c-b2ef-0e16df5ccb76&%25243p=e_as&_branch_match_id=1066917244756057883&_branch_referrer=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32O3WrDMAyFnya7y8%2FiNGGDUgplr2EcW0lEHNuTHUL69JNZdzuQ4fjofJKWlEL8rGsCYzBVKoTKoltrEW5F24lwBaniG0tPOKNTVu5kr0umCnEv2i%2Bu4ziqF6%2F9xgbxu8f14XVkxd4GLmX57NNGPiMAqz2lwaj3GNG7GRwQT%2F%2FeISb%2BR5kWAmU4i6d%2FttjlXYLXdQYgyHxkIR6JdijaXnsisCqDEg37w%2FRxaRozlKOGvuxEp8uxhals4L0300XrceiZI5g4DJtCK19nSoJgz9%2Be1GoLCmf3byj6nTT8RX4AeKJDIlEBAAA%3D) some insights on why fentanyl is suitable only for certain surgeries and not all:

> Fentanyl is commonly used during induction of general anesthesia to attenuate the sympathetic response to intubation with an endotracheal tube. Not all surgeries require general anesthesia. Sometimes it’s used during sedation cases because it has a short duration of action.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on your question, but I'm pretty sure the downvotes on this answer are because you cited an anonymous surgeon. Yeah, I get it that they've been verified as being a surgeon by reddit moderators, but I have no idea what that verification involves, and above all I have no idea how much that person actually knows about anesthesia.

Comment: @CareyGregory agreed, I'd welcome a more verified/sourced answer.